# What is an easy way to pivot table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, pivot

Could anyone lend some help on how to pivot tables in MYSQL? My table looks like this:

```
OU  DataPeriod  RateA   RateB   RateC 
A1  201707      0.1     0.2     null
A1  201707                      0.3
```

I would love to "transpose" this table a bit so that it looks like this:

```
OU  DataPeriod  Rate    Index
A1  201707      0.1     A
A1  201707      0.2     B
A1  201707      0.3     C
```

I have tried different ways, didn't really turn out what I need. Is there a quick way to do this? Many thanks for anyone's kind help!

Comment: That's an unpivot rather than pivot and you get lots of solutions if you google mysql unpivot.

Comment: What are the values for ratea and rateb in row 2 are they nulls or soemthing else? and where does the index column magically appear from?

Comment: They are nulls, all empty fields are nulls, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: The source datatable doesnt have that "Index" column, and that is one of the issues I am having trouble with..

Comment: Then you have to tell us what the logic is for generating it.

Comment: I guess, if the number is from "RateA", then I assign "A" to Index, if from "RateB", then I assign "B" to index.. not sure if this is the SQL way of expressing logic..

Comment: So if you get another 2 rows for ou = a2 then they would get a,b,c for the index?

Comment: Yes, they would still get "A","B","C" for index, depending on which column(RateA, RateB or RateC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is just a series of queries that are combined via union all

```
Select OU ,DataPeriod , RateA as rate, 'A' as indexcol
From yourtable
Where RateA is not null
Union all
Select OU ,DataPeriod , RateB as rate, 'B' as indexcol
From yourtable
Where RateB is not null
...
```

Repeat as necessary

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. The 'A' as index part is giving me an error though..

Comment: Probably because "index" is a reserved word. Choose a different column name

Comment: Haha, that is correct! This works like charm. Big big thanks!